# Javascript: Make the transcription div scroll as the audio plays the highlighted text

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make my transcription div scroll in sync with the highlighted text (and keep the hightlighted text on top of the container) as the audio is played but I'm having some difficulties with the logic. Any tips you could give me?

I have tried to make it scroll into view if the highlighted text exists, but that didnt help.

example code I tried:

```
if (currentTime >= startTime && currentTime <= endTime) {
          isHighlighted = true;

          const lineContainer = document.getElementById(`line-${index}`);
          if (lineContainer) {
            lineContainer.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' });
          }
        } else {
          isHighlighted = false;

if (lineContainer) {
      lineContainer.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' });
    }
```

Current code I'm trying to rework.

```
function displayTranscription(vttData, currentTime) {
    const transcriptionDiv = document.getElementById('transcription');
    transcriptionDiv.innerHTML = ''; 
  
    const lines = vttData.split('\n');
    let isHighlighted = false;
  
    lines.forEach(line => {
      if (/^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3} --> \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}/.test(line)) {
        const [startTime, endTime] = line.split(' --> ').map(timeString => {
          const [hours, minutes, seconds] = timeString.split(':').map(parseFloat);
          return hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds;
        });
  
        if (currentTime && currentTime >= startTime && currentTime <= endTime) {
          isHighlighted = true;
        } else {
          isHighlighted = false;
        }
      } else if (line.trim() !== '') {
        const span = document.createElement('span');
        span.textContent = line;
        if (isHighlighted) {
          span.className = 'highlight';
        }
        transcriptionDiv.appendChild(span);
        transcriptionDiv.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
      }
    });
  }
  
  
  function updateHighlighting(vttData, currentTime) {
    const transcriptionDiv = document.getElementById('transcription');
    transcriptionDiv.innerHTML = ''; 
  
    const lines = vttData.split('\n');
    let isHighlighted = false;
  
    lines.forEach(line => {
      if (/^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3} --> \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}/.test(line)) {
        const [startTime, endTime] = line.split(' --> ').map(timeString => {
          const [hours, minutes, seconds] = timeString.split(':').map(parseFloat);
          return hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds;
        });
  
        if (currentTime >= startTime && currentTime <= endTime) {
          isHighlighted = true;
        } else {
          isHighlighted = false;
        }
      } else if (line.trim() !== '') {
        const span = document.createElement('span');
        span.textContent = line;
        if (isHighlighted) {
          span.className = 'highlight';
        }
        transcriptionDiv.appendChild(span);
        transcriptionDiv.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
      }
    });
  }
  
  const audio = document.querySelector('.audio');
  
  fetch('/VTT/transcription-audio.vtt')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => displayTranscription(data))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching VTT file:', error));
  
  audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {
    const currentTime = audio.currentTime;
    fetch('/VTT/transcription-audio.vtt')
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data => updateHighlighting(data, currentTime))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching VTT file:', error));
  });
```

My css is as follows:

```
#audio-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; 
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 2%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}

#audio {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto; 
}

.audio[poster] {
  border-radius: 0 0 2rem 2rem;
}

.audio {
  width: 100%; 
  background: white;
}


#transcription {
  white-space: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: left;
  overflow-y: auto; 
  max-height: 850px;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: #ffeb3b;
  font-weight: bold;
}

``
```